# VB.NET: Multiple Lines in email

Tags: vb.net, smtpclient

I have tried multiple variations of the following code, but I still get the same result.  I am trying to have the last line "Issue Description: ...." to appear on a new line.

I have tried vbCrLf, vbCr, and & Environment.NewLine & _
None of which work.

Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Just a note: The other emails are properly formatted.  Also, if I add put 2 vbCr (s) at the end of the 'Issue Title' line then it looks normal.

This one in particular seems to be a thorn in my side.

The result:

[image]

The code:

```
Dim mail As New MailMessage()
Dim strbody As String

strbody = Nothing

'set the addresses
mail.From = New MailAddress("email.address@server.com")
mail.[To].Add(Email_Add)

'set the content
mail.Subject = Issue_Num & " Issue has been created."
strbody = "Your issue has been created." & vbCr & vbCr
strbody += "The Issue Team has received the following issue: " & vbCrLf
strbody += "Issue ID: " & Issue_Num & vbCrLf
strbody += "Issue Title: " & Email_Summary & vbLf
strbody += "Issue Description: " & Description & vbCrLf

mail.Body = strbody


'set the server
Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("mailhost.mailserver.com", 15)

'send the message

smtp.Send(mail)
```

When I use the following code:

```
 'set the content
mail.Subject = Issue_Num & " Issue has been created."
strbody = "Your issue has been created." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
strbody += "The Issue Team has received the following issue: " & vbCrLf
strbody += "Issue ID: " & Issue_Num & vbCrLf
strbody += "Issue Title: " & Email_Summary & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
strbody += "Issue Description: " & Description & vbCrLf
```

I get this:

[image]

Comment: Any reason in particular why you're using all different line endings?

Comment: @Blindy I just updated all the tags to vcCrLf

Comment: 2 hours of sleep here but isn't your 2nd output what you want? It matches your `vbCrLf`'s perfectly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the mail format into HTML like this:

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = True
```

And then add an html break tag (`<br />`) where you want a line break.

Answer (score 0):

```
Message.to.Add(ToEmail)
Message.From = New MailAddress(FromEmail)
Message.Attachment.Add(Attachment)
Dim body As String = "Hello user" + ","
body += "<br /><br />"

body += tbEmailBody.Text.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br />")
'This line and the "Message.IsBodyHtml = True" are the important lines to get it to work.

body += "<br /><br />"
body += "<br /><br />Thanks"
Message.Body = body
Message.IsBodyHtml = True
```

I didn't see this exact answer but maybe I overlooked it.
Maybe someone else will find it useful
Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

dim str as string

put html code as string like this-

```
str = "<table> <tr> <td> Name : </td> <td> Yuwraj D. Bramhankar </td></tr><tr> <td> Address : </td> <td> 439, Anand Nagar, Nagpur 09 - INDIA</td></tr> </table>"


 mail.Body = str
Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("mailhost.mailserver.com", 15)
```

'send the message here

```
smtp.Send(mail)
```